# Finding closest feature to given address in ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-python-api

I'd like to find the closest open space (i.e. a park, square, playground) from a City of Boston MapServer using Python's ArcGIS package.

I'd like to use `arcgis.features.use_proximity.find_nearest()` method. To that end I've geocoded the address and passed it first to a Feature constructor and then added that Feature to a FeatureCollection.

My ArcGIS public account does not support spatial analysis.

Does anyone have any recommendations for finding the nearest open space?

get_open_spaces.py

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import Feature, FeatureCollection, FeatureLayer, FeatureSet
from arcgis.features.use_proximity import find_nearest
from arcgis.geocoding import Geocoder
import logging, os, requests


def _get_open_spaces():
    """                                                                                                          
    Gets the open spaces from the City's MapServer                                                               
    """
    open_spaces_url = "http://gis.cityofboston.gov/arcgis/rest/" \
        + "services/EnvironmentEnergy/OpenData/MapServer/7"
    f = FeatureLayer(url = open_spaces_url)
    return f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = ************
    passwrd = *************
    log_filename = "log/open_spaces_log"
    try:
        os.remove(log_filename)
    except OSError:
        pass
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_filename, level=logging.DEBUG)
    my_address = "94 Sawyer Ave., Boston, MA, 02125"
    g = GIS(username = username, password=passwrd)
    logging.debug("Using address: %s" % my_address)
    logging.debug("getting open spaces feature layer")
    near_layer = _get_open_spaces()
    assert near_layer, "something went wrong with the near_layer"
    logging.debug("now we're trying to get the address into its on feature_layer")
    coded_address = Geocoder(my_address, g)
    address_as_feature = Feature('point', coded_address)
    analysis_layer = FeatureCollection(address_as_feature.as_dict)
    find_nearest(analysis_layer, near_layer)
```

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/49699470/820534